# Is there any way to play Hammerfight with a gamepad?

Tags: hammerfight

Hammerfight, while being a great game, is also excellent at annihilating your wrist, as controlling the game is done by performing circular motions with the mouse almost constantly.

When I first got the game, I looked for a way to translate gamepad input to mouse input so that I could play the game without inflicting physical harm on myself. The results I came up with were far from satisfactory, however (I found some way to turn my PS3's controller input into mouse input, but it was very sluggish and simply wouldn't do at all).

This site didn't exist back then, so I ask you, has anyone managed to set up a gamepad to work with this game in a way that doesn't feel like you are sacrificing control for convenience?

Comment: I love the idea for this game, and the control scheme is brilliant, but it's also infuriatingly difficult to actually use.  I quit in the first fight.

Comment: If it was the mouse specifically that put you off, as opposed to the control mechanics, you should really try the game with a gamepad (though I don't know whether it works with anything other than an Xbox360 controller, which I made my DualShock3 emulate).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, erm, I'm not exactly sure how to tell you this, but... Hammerfight supports gamepads out of the box.

I just booted it up with my wireless Xbox 360 gamepad plugged in, and it picked it up immediately. The only thing you have to do is disable multy-mouse in the settings.

Comment: Well I'll be damned... it never occurred to me to just try it out as I never saw any official mention of such support. Maybe I just managed to miss it.